# FFMPEG : create a looping video with specific time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, java, android, gif

I'm trying to convert a GIF file into video and merge the output video with an audio file, so the final result will be a video + audio.

```
public static String makeVideo(String inputGifPath, String outputPath, int width, int height) {
        return "-f gif -y -i " + inputGifPath + " -vf crop=" + width + ":" + height + ":0:40,scale=1280:720,setsar=1 " + outputPath;
}
```

The code above convert the input GIF into video file keeping the same duration of the GIF.

I wonder if there's any way to convert the GIF into video with a specific time for example, I want the video output to loop for **3min:20s**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-stream_loop` input option:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.gif -i audio.mp3 -vf crop=" + width + ":" + height + ":0:40,scale=1280:720,setsar=1,format=yuv420p -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- The extra options `-fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M` are likely needed in this case. See [My ffmpeg output always add extra 30s of silence at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804507/).
- Make sure the output frame rate isn't lower than 6 or so or players won't like it. You can see output frame rate in the console output log. Otherwise add the [fps filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps), such as `fps=10`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's worked but take too long to finish, I use another method and it's worked fine

Answer (score 1):

The @llogan answer worked for me, but for some reason its take long time to finish the processing, I ended this using the following :

1 - Converting GIF to video (with the same duration of the GIF file)

```
-f gif -y -i input.gif -vf crop=540:402:0:40,scale=1280:720,setsar=1 gifToVideo.mp4
```

2 - Looping the output video for X time (X == audio duration/GIF duration in sec)

```
-y -stream_loop xTime -i gifToVideo.mp4 -c copy videoNoSound.mp4
```

3 - Merging the `videoNoSound.mp4` with and audio file :

```
-y -i videoNoSound.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac longVideo.mp4
```

4 - Cutting the `longVideo.mp4` to match the audio duration :

```
-y -i longVideo.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t audioDuration -async 1 -c copy finalVideo.mp4
```